# Node.js: async-await with/without Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

While I was prototyping some logic I need to implement for my project, I noticed some interesting behaviour with async-await and Promise.

```
// Notice this one returns a Promise
var callMe = function(i) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(i)
            resolve(`${i} is called :)`)
        }, (i+1)*1000)
    })  
}

// But this one doesn't
var callYou = function(i) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(i)
    }, (i+1)*1000)
}

async function run() {
    console.log("Start")
    for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        let val = await callYou(i)
         # also try with callMe()
         #let val = await callMe(i)
        console.log(val)
    }
    console.log("End")
}

run()
```

With `let val = await callYou(i)`, the result looks something like this

```
Start
callYou()
callYou()
callYou()
End
0
1
2
```

whereas with `let val = await callMe(i)`, the result looks something like this

```
Start
0
0 is called :)
1
1 is called :)
2
2 is called :)
End
```

I was expecting two functions to behave similarly since async function essentially returns a promise. Could someone shed light on why this is happening please?

Comment: WTH are you using the `new` operator?

Comment: oops, that's a typo. my bad

Comment: `[...] since async function essentially returns a promise.[...]` what do you mean with that? The only function with the `async` keyword is `run`. `callYou` is neither `async` nor does it return a Promise.

Answer (score 0):

`async` functions return promises but neither `callYou` or `callMe` are `async` functions and even if they where, `callYou` will be fulfilled when the function returns not when the callback passes to the `setTimeout` function is executed.

Comment: ahh, that makes sense. callMe()  returns a Promise, so I guess the loop was waiting for the Promise in callMe() to be resolved before executing the next callMe(). Thanks